# PHP echo array data

Tags: php, arrays

I want to access the data in the php array. I have tried array[0] and array['Name'] but i dont get an output. here is my code:

```
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$sql_1 = "SELECT UserID FROM users WHERE username=$user";
$result_1 = mysqli_query($sql_1);
$uID = mysqli_fetch_array($result_1);
if ($uID=NULL) {
    echo 'null';
} else {
    echo $uID[0];
}
```

Now I am not getting any output from the echo command. So what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: try `print_r($uID);` to see exactly what you *do* have in the `$uID` variable. Also, google "PHP PDO" and use the `PDO` extension with prepared statements for database access. **mysql/mysqli** must die.

Comment: The usage of `mysqli_query` in that form is `mysqli_query($link,$query)` where your `$link` is the connection to your database, say from `mysqli_connect` -- you don't seem to supply any link in to `mysqli_query`.

Comment: print_r($uID); returns no data. I tried the same command on my database and it returns the right value.

Comment: why do you think there is anything in this array? (assuming all the thousand preceding errors)

Comment: @mathematical.coffee how would I assign right values to $link?
i tried $link = ('127.0.0.1','root','','wf_db');
sorry I am new to PHP and MySQL.

Comment: instead of writing some code at random, you need to run some tutorial examples first and make them WORK. and only after that try to alter the code to suit your needs.

Comment: This thing is not working because the first time you run the IF statement you assign NULL to $uid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Part `if ($uID=NULL)` is always <strike>true</strike>[UPDATED:false], because you're doing an assignment rather than a comparism (that would be `if ( $uID == NULL )`)

Comment: Actually, it's always `false` (or `null` which evaluates to `false`). The result of an assignment is the value assigned. You still nailed the *main* problem though, so +1

Comment: @Phil Isn't it just the value of the assignment? So in this case `NULL`, but if you would do `if ($uID = 'something') // something (truthy)`.